# Retaining paragraph numbering in docx using the R officer package

Tags: r, nlp, officer, text-manipulation

**How can I retain the numbering of paragraphs when extracting text from a docx file?**

I'm doing some NLP-ML work on a bunch of docx files, and to begin with I need to break up each doc into a dataframe. I'm working with contracts, such that almost every paragraph is numbered, e.g most of the text I'm dealing with looks like this:

> 1.17. The Agent will provide the attendant resources as set out in Annex 3 bla bla bla
>
> 1.17.1. The Agent will ensure that attendant resources are bla bla bla
>
> 1.18. An indicative Authority resource profile is set out in bla bla bla.
>
> etc

The `docx_summary()` of the `officer` package function lays out the text in a dataframe wonderfully, except that it doesn't retain the paragraph numbering. The result is that I get a dataframe where the text looks like this:

```
The Agent will provide the attendant resources as set out in Annex 3 bla bla bla

The Agent will ensure that attendant resources are bla bla bla

An indicative Authority resource profile is set out in bla bla bla.
```

I guessed this is to do with how Word defines numbering as a Style rather than plain text, and I can see in the `docx_summary()` output, the `$style_name` variable has Headings 1 through 4 according to the numbering hierarchy in the docx. But I can't figure out how to extract the actual numbering and apply it to each paragraph in the `docx_summary` outputted dataframe.

The output I want is the same `docx_summary()` dataframe, but with an added numbering column, to look like this:

```
output_df <- data.frame(content_type = "paragraph", style_name = "heading 2", numbering = "1.17", text = "The Agent will provide the attendant resources as set out in Annex 3 bla bla bla")

> output_df
  content_type style_name numbering text
1    paragraph  heading 2      1.17 The Agent will provide the attendant resources as set out in Annex 3 bla bla bla
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The only solution I have found till the moment is to manually run the following VBA script: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/is-there-a-way-to-remove-bullets-but-retain/06b677be-63a5-4f07-9dc2-6a66c46b7e7f